# Spring boot webflux serving static resources from a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I haven't used Spring Boot for a while and seem to have a problem getting Spring to serve static assets. My project contains multiple modules - one of which is `webui`. It builds an Angular application and archives it into a `jar`. This dependency is then consumed from the `webapp` and is included in the fat jar. I have the following `WebConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer
{


    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> redirectToIndex()
    {
        ClassPathResource index = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html");
        List<String> extensions = List.of("js", "css", "ico", "png", "jpg", "gif");
        RequestPredicate spaPredicate = path("/api/**").or(path("/error"))
                                                       .or(pathExtension(extensions::contains))
                                                       .negate();

        return route().resource(spaPredicate, index).build();
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("*.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath*:/static")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(Duration.ofHours(1)));

        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath*:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(Duration.ofHours(1)))
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new EncodedResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }


}
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to be working and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.
There is indeed a `static/index.html` and `static/assets/` resource, but that's under a 3rd party dependency. I have a feeling that `static/index.html` refers to the top root of the `fat jar`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I really think that people need to stop just marking questions for closure, just to be "helpful moderators". The question is actually well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find enough information about on the internet I decided to find a "workaround". When you build a "fat jar" with Spring Boot you will get something like the following jar:

```
webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:

+ BOOT-INF/
  + classes
  + lib/
    + all dependencies of the `webapp` module
    + this is also where the `webui` jar would be placed.
  + classpath.idx
  + layers.idx

+ META-INF/

+ org/springframework/boot/loader/
```

As I suspected the `ClassPathResource("static/index.html")` is not able to locate the resources under `BOOT-INF/lib/webui.jar` which is why the resource is not served.

My workaround is to extract the `webui.jar` into `build/resources/main/static`:

```
register<Copy>("copyAssets") {
    mustRunAfter(project(":webapp-ui").tasks.getByName("jar"))
    dependsOn(project(":webapp-ui").tasks.getByName("jar"))
    doFirst {
        delete("${project.layout.buildDirectory.get()}/resources/main/static")
    }
    from(zipTree(project(":webapp-ui").layout.buildDirectory.dir("distributions/cs-accounting-webapp-ui-${version}.jar"))) {
        include("static/**")
    }
    into("${project.layout.buildDirectory.get()}/resources/main/") // Destination directory in otherModule
}

named<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
    dependsOn(named("copyAssets"))
}

named<BootRun>("bootRun") {
    dependsOn(named("copyAssets"))
}
```

I would love to fix this in a way that does not involve this workaround.
If anybody knows the answer I'd accept it.